# Typescript variable inside file.onload is undefined

Tags: variables, scope, undefined

```
  filePhotoValue: any = "xexe";

  sendFile(file) {

    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e:any) {
      console.log(this.filePhotoValue);
    };

  }
```

Why filePhotoValue inside reader.onload consoles `"undefined"` instead of `xexe`? There is no compilation errors and I'd like to set some value to `filePhotoValue inside` reader.onload.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While you are inside the onload method, you loose the context of "this" that is outside the method. To fix this you have two solutions:
Save the "this" context in another variable:

```
sendFile(file) {

    var reader = new FileReader();

    var self = this;    

    reader.onload = function (e:any) {
      console.log(self.filePhotoValue);
    };

  }
```

or bind the current context to the function:

```
sendFile(file) {

    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e:any) {
      console.log(this.filePhotoValue);
    }.bind(this);

  }
```